# where to use multiprocessing in multi-loop program

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, hpc

I am running a program that uses [a lot of] looping to perform a type of bootstrap analysis. The computational step can take a long time (60+) seconds, which means that collectively this program could take almost a week to run serially. I have tried using multiprocessing on a high performance cluster - using `concurrent.futures` - but the analysis is just as slow.  I know that misusing multiprocessing can lead to same/worse performance than serial, so I'm wondering at what point in my code this happens.

My analysis program looks like this, serially:

```py
def analysis(dataset, subset_sizes, n_iters):
    for size in subset_sizes:
        for _ in range(n_iters):
            subsampled_dataset = random_sample(dataset, size)
            computation(subsampled_dataset)


for dataset in datasets:
    for _ in range(n_trials):
        analysis(dataset, **kwargs)
```

using multiprocessing, it looks like this:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

    futures = []
    for dataset in datasets: # here, datasets looks like [datasetN_trialN, ...] to use one loop
        futures.append(executor.submit(analysis, **kwargs))

    results = [f.result() for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
```

Should I be calling executor.submit at a different point in my code?

Comment: You can allocate 128 cores to your application, but if the application is limited by available RAM quantity, you're limited by the RAM quantity. As such, I would suggest you focus on a holistic approach. You may be limited to RAM allocation, you may be limited on VRAM (if applicable), you may be limited on disk read speeds, etc. - determine the bottlenecks, and then you have a starting point for improving the efficiency of your analysis. This is, of course, assuming there are no problems with the application, you should also investigate memory leaks, API calls, etc.

Comment: Multiprocessing tends to be limited by the data transmission between the initial master process and all others. This often causes a poor scalability of the program. There is not much to do since multithreading is limited by the GIL. The best is not to use Python for parallel computing but lower level languages or tools like Cython/Numba that can bypass the GIL. Python is clearly not great for parallelism (it has not been designed for this though).